# Converting epoch time in milliseconds to time stamp to UTC error

Tags: python, datetime, unix, pyspark, epoch

I am currently trying to convert a date stored in an epoch format in milliseconds to a timestamp.

```
    .withColumn(
        "date_var",
        from_utc_timestamp(
            from_unixtime("timestamp_var" / 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "PST"
        )
```

Unfortunately this is erroring out with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-df435784865f> in <module>
     32         "date_var",
     33         from_utc_timestamp(
---> 34             from_unixtime("timestamp_var" / 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "PST"
     35         ),
     36     )

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax but would welcome any help!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the column and divide it by 1000. Pyspark cannot divide a string by 1000.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn(
        "date_var",
        F.from_utc_timestamp(
            F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp_var") / 1000,
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            "PST"
        )
```